# UserProfileChangeCollection is not recognizing the change if a property is associated with term store

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

We want to monitor the "User Profile Changes", so have used "UserProfileChangeCollection". It works perfectly for "UserProfileMultiValueChange" and "UserProfileSingleValueChange" however it is not working if term store is associated with a property.

Could find the below data using Powershell however OM is not recognizing the update information for the term store associated property. Is this expected? or am I missing something here?

ChangedValue    : IT
ProfileProperty : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Property
NewValueProfile :
NewValueTerm    : Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Term
SecondaryValue  : IT
ChangedUser     : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile
AccountName     : domain\accountName
Id              : 12551787
ChangeType      : Add
ObjectType      : MultiValueProperty
EventTime       : 9/29/2011 9:32:51 AM
PrivacyPolicy   : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.Property
ChangedProfile  : Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile

Code used:

```
private void updateUserProfileChanges(string _mySiteLocal, string _mySiteCentral, string currentUser)
{  
  //string currentUser ="";
  string localLastUpdateDate ="";
  string centalLastUpdateDate ="";
  DateTime localLastUpdateDateTime;
  string msg = "";
  bool isRedirectReq = false;
  SPUserToken userToken;
  //HttpContext currentContext;

  //currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
  userToken = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.UserToken;

  try
  {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
    {
    using (SPSite localMySite = new SPSite(_mySiteLocal,userToken ))
    {
        SPServiceContext localContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(localMySite);
        UserProfileManager localProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(localContext); 
            HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
        HttpContext.Current = null;


        UserProfile localUserProfile = localProfileManager.GetUserProfile(currentUser); 

        using (SPSite centralMySite = new SPSite(_mySiteCentral,userToken ))
        {
            SPServiceContext centralContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(centralMySite);
            UserProfileManager centralProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(centralContext);
            UserProfile centralUserProfile = centralProfileManager.GetUserProfile(currentUser); 

            centalLastUpdateDate = centralUserProfile.CurrentChangeToken.ToString();
            //msg = centralUserProfile.GetProfileValueCollection("CellPhone").Count.ToString();
            //msg = centralUserProfile["CellPhone"].ToString();

                if (localUserProfile.GetProfileValueCollection("LocalLastUpdateDate").Count >= 1)
                {
                        localLastUpdateDate = localUserProfile["LocalLastUpdateDate"].ToString();
            }
            else
                {
                localUserProfile["LocalLastUpdateDate"].Value = centalLastUpdateDate ;
                localLastUpdateDate = centalLastUpdateDate ;
                localUserProfile.Commit();
                }

            if(centalLastUpdateDate != localLastUpdateDate )
            {
                msg = "Should be updated..!";
                string[] centralChagneTokens = centalLastUpdateDate.Split(';');
                string[] localChagneTokens = localLastUpdateDate.Split(';');
                string localLastChangeTokenDate = localChagneTokens[2].ToString();

                UserProfileChangeQuery userProfileChangeQuery;
                UserProfileChangeToken userProfileChangeToken;

                //UserProfileChangeDictionary userProfileChangeDictionary;
                UserProfileChangeCollection userProfileChangeCollection ;

                localLastUpdateDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(localLastChangeTokenDate);
                userProfileChangeQuery = new UserProfileChangeQuery(true, true);
                userProfileChangeToken = new UserProfileChangeToken(localLastUpdateDateTime);

                userProfileChangeQuery.ChangeTokenStart = userProfileChangeToken;
                userProfileChangeQuery.PersonalizationSite = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.SiteMembership = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.Anniversary = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.Colleague = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.UserProfile = true;

                userProfileChangeQuery.Update = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.Add = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.Delete = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.SingleValueProperty = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.MultiValueProperty = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.Custom = true;
                userProfileChangeQuery.UpdateMetadata = true;


                //userProfileChangeCollection = localUserProfile.GetChanges();

                userProfileChangeCollection = centralUserProfile.GetChanges(userProfileChangeQuery);
                //userProfileChangeCollection = centralUserProfile.GetChanges();
                //userProfileChangeDictionary = localUserProfile.UserProfilePropertyValueChange(userProfileChangeQuery);
                //IEnumerator userProfileChangeCollection = userProfileChangeDictionary.GetEnumerator();

                //while (userProfileChangeDictionary.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
                //{
                //}

                msg  = "Begining loop";
                foreach (UserProfileChange userProfileChange in userProfileChangeCollection )
                {
                    //if (userProfileChange is UserProfileSingleValueChange)
                    //{
                        //UserProfileSingleValueChange propertyChange = (UserProfileSingleValueChange)userProfileChange;                     
                        //localUserProfile[propertyChange.ProfileProperty.Name].Value = propertyChange.NewValue;
                        //msg  = "Inside singlevalue properties";
                    //}
                    //else if (userProfileChange is UserProfileMultiValueChange)
                    //{
                        //UserProfileMultiValueChange propertyChange = (UserProfileMultiValueChange)userProfileChange;
                        //if(propertyChange.ChangeType.ToString() == "Add")
                        //{
                            //localUserProfile[propertyChange.ProfileProperty.Name].Add((Object)"c@d.com");
                        //}
                        //propertyChange will have the new and old value of profile fileds
                        //msg = propertyChange.ChangeType.ToString() + " : " + propertyChange.ProfileProperty.Name;
                        //msg  = "Inside Multivalue properties";
                    //}
                    //msg = userProfileChange.GetType().ToString();
                    msg += userProfileChange.Id.ToString();
                    //msg  = userProfileChange.ProfileProperty.Name;

                    //if (change is UserProfilePropertyValueChange)
                    //{
                        //UserProfilePropertyValueChange propertyChange = (UserProfilePropertyValueChange)change;
                        //msg = propertyChange.ProfileProperty.Name;
                    //}
                }

                // section update term store properities....


                    if (centralUserProfile.GetProfileValueCollection("multiValuePropTest").Count >= 1)
                    {
                            for(int k=0; k< centralUserProfile.GetProfileValueCollection("multiValuePropTest").Count; k++)
                    {
                        //localLastUpdateDate = localUserProfile["LocalLastUpdateDate"].ToString();

                    }
                }               

                //msg = localLastUpdateDateTime.ToString() ;

                //localUserProfile["LocalLastUpdateDate"].Value = centalLastUpdateDate ;
                //localUserProfile.Commit();

                //Page.Response.Redirect(_mySiteLocal);
                //isRedirectReq = true;

                //msg = "Final step";
            }
            else
            {
                //User Profile is upto date and there are no further updates pending...
                //Leaving user control...
                msg = "Upto date..!";
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
    }
    });
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    msg =  ex.Message;  
  }
  finally
  {
    //if (isRedirectReq )
    //  Page.Response.Redirect(_mySiteLocal + "/Person.aspx");
    //HttpContext.Current = currentContext;
    Page.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com?k=" + msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: A flag is only seen by a moderator. Try offering a bounty for this question in order to get more visibility to everyone.

Comment: Can you remove the unnecessary or commented code. It will help to focus where the problem is. Also, please mention the output you get with the code above(like you did for powershell)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *UserProfile.GetChanges(UserProfileChangeToken)* instead of  *UserProfile.GetChanges(ProfileBaseChangeQuery)*. It will give you broader level of changes.